# Java RegEx to Check for Not starts with Specific String but contains multiple Strings

Tags: java, regex, string, groovy

I am trying to match String messages that doesnt starts with String `Line` or `line` but has the substrings  `TIMEKEEPER`,`CLIENT` and `LAW FIRM` using the below RegEx

```
def regEX = "^((?!(Line|line)+).).?(\\bTIMEKEEPER\\b|\\bCLIENT\\b|\\bLAW FIRM\\b|).*\$"
```

Below are some Sample messages.

```
Line 1 : Missing required fields //returns false as expected
line 2 : No Delimiter //returns false as expected
PL is not approved TIMEKEEPER //returns true as expected
CLIENT  ABC is not authorized  //returns true as expected
LAW FIRM address is required //returns true as expected
```

But the issue is, above RegEX is just matching all the messages that doesnt start with String `Line` or `line` only, its not checking for the matching substrings `TIMEKEEPER`,`CLIENT` and `LAW FIRM` in the message.
ABove RegEX shouldn't match below messages but the RegEX returning true for below messages too, Can someone please help me fixing the RegEX to not to match below type of messages.

```
address is required //returns true instead of false
ABC is not authorized //returns true instead of false
```

Comment: Try `def regEx = /^(?![Ll]ine\b).*\b(TIMEKEEPER|CLIENT|LAW FIRM)\b.*$/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, you're just incredible! How do you track SO?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, yeah I see regex ;] I was rather asking how you track new questions? It seems you're online all the time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a regex like this (defined with a slashy string):

```
def regEx = /^(?![Ll]ine\b).*\b(TIMEKEEPER|CLIENT|LAW FIRM)\b.*$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yxI8RO/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?![Ll]ine\b)` - no whole word `Line` or `line` allowed at the start
- `.*` - any 0+ chars as many as possible
- `\b(TIMEKEEPER|CLIENT|LAW FIRM)\b` - any of the 3 whole words in ALLCAPS
- `.*$` - the rest of the line.

Comment: You may also use a case insensitive modifier and write the pattern as [`/(?i)^(?!line\b).*\b(TIMEKEEPER|CLIENT|LAW FIRM)\b.*$/`](https://ideone.com/0YcCeq)

Comment: Awesome, I was about to ask for case sensitive RegEx, thanks you so much, I really appreciate ur effort

Comment: can you please help me with this problem  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47717505/groovy-create-a-map-with-jax-b-objects-specific-attributes

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to match *all* the substrings TIMEKEEPER, CLIENT, and LAW FIRM, or at least one? This seems like an abuse of regular expressions, frankly, when Java has a perfectly good `String#startsWith()` method. You're simply looking for a small set of literal substrings here.

Comment: No abuse here at all because OP is interested in matching the 3 alternatives as *whole words*. Regex is meant to match *whole words*.